# how to get the video format of youtube so that this video format in avplayer in swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, video, youtube

i need some help on how to get the youtube video format for the youtube urls.I'm trying to create a video player in swift ios project in which a user pastes a youtube url and clicks 'go' and the youtube url is appended with a video format (like .FLV or .MP4). I need this as avkit needs the video format to play that type of format.

Comment: It doesn't work like that. Adding a file extension does not automatically make the video stream playable. You need to use the Youtube SDK instead.

Comment: @Eric D so using youtube sdk will convert the url to the video format?

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/23131/623314